# Trying to set input by typing anywhere in jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, forms

I am trying to make a game where people don't have to click inside the input field in order to type, and I have the input field value being set by typing, except each type a new letter is typed, it resets the input field rather than adding the value. This is the code:

```
$( document).on( "keydown", function( event ) {
  $( ".inputfield" ).val(String.fromCharCode(event.which))
});
```

Comment: get the val of the input first then append the next code

Comment: You'll need to validate the input, otherwise you'll get control characters in your input

Answer (score 1):

You need to add to your current value instead of overwriting it.

```js
$( document).on( "keydown", function( event ) {
  const current_value = $( ".inputfield" ).val();
  const new_value = current_value + String.fromCharCode(event.which);
  $( ".inputfield" ).val(new_value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" class='inputfield' />
```

Comment: Thank you! How about if I want to use the delete button to delete the last character?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `val(function)` which exposes the current value that you concatenate.

Note you will want to validate the `which` is in a character code range

```js
$( document).on( "keydown", function( event ) {
   $( ".inputfield" ).val(function(i,curr){
     return curr + String.fromCharCode(event.which)
  });      
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" class='inputfield' />
```

Comment: Thank you! How about if I want to use the delete button to delete the last character?

Comment: Store the current value using `.data()` then slice that string and set new value